# What would be the cardinality of performing a cartesian product on two power sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have set $A = \{7,\,4,\,3\}$ and set $B = \{3,\,4,\,5,\,6,\,7\}$.

I wish to find the cardinality of $P(A\times B)$.

This is my approach:

I know that the cardinality of the power set of $A$ is $2^3$, I know that the cardinality of the power set of $B$ is $2^5$.

Would the cardinality be $256$?

Comment: As per any other finite set: count the number $n$ of the elements of the set and its power set will have $2^n$ members.

Comment: Hint: $A\times B$ has $15$ elements. What you've computed is the cardinality of $P(A)\times P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a finite set $A$, we have that $|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$. In your case we have $|P(A\times B)|=2^{|A\times B|}$. Since $$|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|=15$$ we have that $$|P(A\times B)|=2^{15}=32768$$